# How to write multiple if/else if conditions in R on Row record selection

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a simple question on adding a Flag to indicate if the day is out of the scheduled range. As shown in the following image, each  should be occurred within a 6 day range, e.g., for Week 2, the  should be 9 <= STDTY <= 21, otherwise it will be flagged as Flag="Y".

```
if (data$VISIT=="Screening" & data$STDTY>=-1) {
  data$Flag="Y"
} else if (data$VISIT=="Day 1" & data$STDTY!=1) {
  sv_domain$Flag="Y"
} else if (data$VISIT=="Week 2" & data$STDTY<(2*7+1-6)) {
  data$Flag="Y"
} else if (data$VISIT=="Week 2" & data$STDTY>(2*7+1+6)) {
  data$Flag="Y"
```

.......

I know it doesn't work, please help me out, thanks!

[image]

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). Images are not the right way to share data/code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if/else` is not vectorized.  We may use `ifelse` or more easily with `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
case_when(data$VISIT=="Screening" & data$STDTY>=-1|
 data$VISIT=="Week 2" & data$STDTY<(2*7+1-6)|
 data$VISIT=="Week 2" & data$STDTY>(2*7+1+6) ~ "Y")
```

---

Or with `ifelse`

```
ifelse(data$VISIT=="Screening" & data$STDTY>=-1|
 data$VISIT=="Week 2" & data$STDTY<(2*7+1-6)|
 data$VISIT=="Week 2" & data$STDTY>(2*7+1+6), "Y", NA)
```

Comment: This is the best solution with case_when. Thanks!